# Prediction intervals for the outcome of a logistic regression with binomial response

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, prediction-interval

Suppose we have a logistic regression model:

$$\begin{align}
P(y=1\vert\mathbf{x}) &= p \\
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) &= \boldsymbol{\beta}\mathbf{x}
\end{align}$$

Given a random sample $D=\{\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}\}$ of size $N$, we can compute confidence intervals for the $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ and correspondingly prediction intervals for $p$, given a certain value $\mathbf{x}^*$ of the predictor vector. This is all very standard and detailed, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423325/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-logistic-regression/14424417#14424417).

Suppose instead that I'm interested in a prediction interval for $y$, given $\mathbf{x}^*$. Of course, it doesn't make any sense at all to compute a prediction *interval* for a single realization of $y$, because $y$ can only take the values 0 and 1, and no value in between. *However*, if we consider $m$ realizations of $y$ for the same fixed value of  $\mathbf{x}^*$ , then this becomes similar (but not identical) to the question of [computing a prediction interval for a binomial random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255570/prediction-interval-for-binomial-random-variable/). This is basically the same situation described by Glen_b in the comments to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26576/58675). Does this question have an answer, apart from the trivial one "use nonparametric bootstrap"?

Comment: can you compute a prediction interval for $log(p / (1-p))$ instead perhaps?

Comment: @HughPerkins I think that the issue is how to combine the uncertainty in _p_ with the uncertainty in binomial sampling also given the uncertainty in _p_. Is there a closed-form solution?

Comment: @EdM you got my point. I wonder if there is a closed form solution or an analytical approximation.

Comment: [offtopic] random idea, it occurs to me that it could be interesting to have a tag like 'open-research-opportunity' for questions like this which/if they are answered in the negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this should work without bootstrapping (which in practice may be the fastest thing tho implement), would be:

1. Assume that a normal approximation for the predicted log-odds ($x \hat{\beta}$) plus/minus its standard error works. Any logistic regression software will provide this.
2. The percentiles of this distribution transform to probabilities via the anti-logit.
3. One can find a (mixture of) beta distribution(s) that approximates the predictive distribution for the probability well.
4. The predictive distribution for the outcome is then a (mixture of) beta-binomial distribution(s with the same mixing weights as used in step 3).

Alternatively, one can "just" integrate out the log-odds from the joint predictive of outcome and log-odds, but I believe that will be a complete mess with no closed form solution.

Comment: You could also just directly simulate from the asymptotic multivariate normal for $\beta-\hat{\beta}$, and then form a mixture of binomials over those values.

Comment: I like the overall idea, but I'm not sure about the details. For example, "find a (mixture of) beta distribution(s) that approximates the predictive distribution for the probability well", How do you this in practice? Could you add an example? Even a low-dimensional one would suffice.

Comment: About your second alternative, if I understand correctly you suggest to write down the joint posterior distribution of outcomes and log-odds (which is a joint distribution between continuous and discrete variables) and integrate out log-odds. I definitely agree that that's going to be a mess. One could salvage the approach using MCMC to estimate the integral, I think. However, I would need MCMC algorithms which work for discrete-continuous variables...I'm not sure which one do. I think  `rstan` (my tool of choice for MCMC) doesn't.

Comment: The proposal by Glen_b is of course very easy: simulate from MVN for the betas, form log - odds, convert too probability, simulate binary outcomes.

Comment: Bjorn, the same question holds for you. How many components should I use in the mixture of binomials? How do I estimate $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ for each component of the mixture? I'm not very familiar with density estimation, unfortunately. Even a reference to a useful package would be enough: I don't expect you two to lay down the theory of beta mixture estimation for me (that would be another question).

Comment: @DeltaIV My suggestion has the same number of components as values you simulated from the MVN; let's say you have a single prediction to create and want to generate $N$ simulations, then you can set up $n+1$ bins to hold the distribution at any value of $\mathbf{x}$ you're predicting for. At each step you simulate your parameter difference vector $\beta-\hat{\beta}$ and then you have a conditional binomial for the prediction. You multiply that conditional pmf by 1/N and add that into the $n+1$ probabilities you're collecting. (These days this simulation would be called a parametric bootstrap.)

Comment: However, if you only had a single predicted value, you can of course shortcut this to essentially a numerical integration\*. For that, compute instead the distribution of $[\beta-\hat{\beta}]x$ (keeping in mind this is 'backwards', then shift it by the constant $\hat{\beta}x$), and across a fine grid of values over that distribution do a probability-weighted version of the suggestion in the previous comment.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry - my comments didn’t make sense. I kept mixing betas, binomials & beta-binomials in my mind. I’m on holiday now and apparently my mind is on holiday too :-) Once I’m back I’ll try to rewrite your comments as an answer and implement it into an R code - not b/c I plan to accept it, but just because this way I’ll be forced to follow the train of thoughts. Thanks to both of you

Comment: I can write this up as something in the form of an answer if you prefer -- I don't mind either way.

Comment: @Glen_b I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: @Glen_b, I would be interested in seeing that answer.

Comment: @DeltaIV, I would be interested in seeing that answer.